# Ruby on Rails: Devise Redirect After Sign Up For Worker Roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise

Using Devise and wanting the user to go to a specific page after they sign up. Here's the kicker; the user can either sign up as a Buyer or a Worker via radio button. When they sign up as a Worker, I want them to go to a specific path.

So far, the code I have now, a Buyer and Worker will both go to the same path. The 'current_user.worker?' code is what I think is not working right.

**new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= radio_button_tag 'user[role]', 'worker' %>
  <%= radio_button_tag 'user[role]', 'buyer' %>
  <%= f.text_field :username %>
  <%= f.email_field :email %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
  <%= f.submit 'Create Account', :class => 'button' %>
<% end %>
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base


   def after_sign_up_path_for(resource_or_scope)
     if current_user.worker?
       account_setup_path
     else 
     end
   end

 end
```

Comment: you should have a method named worker in user model like this `def worker?; role == 'worker' end`

Comment: hey @Octopus-Paul , Yes. I have that method in the user.rb as def worker? return role == 'worker' end

Comment: have you tested worker? method to see it returns the desired result?

Comment: I actually think the  def after_sign_up_path_for  doesn't work. Because I took out the 'if' code out of there and just left account_setup_path  which should of took any new signed up user to that path and it doesn't.

Comment: I found this https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-up-(registration) . maybe it will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your user.rb .. assuming you have a column in your users table called "role" and it's either "worker" or "buyer".

```
def worker?
  (self.role == "worker")
end

def buyer?
  (self.role == "buyer")
end
```

Then this should work after signup... put it in the same controller as your signup code (Most likely RegistrationController?)

```
   def after_sign_up_path_for(resource_or_scope)
       account_setup_path if current_user.worker?
       some_other_path if current_user.buyer?

       # And if they are not a buyer or worker .. well. Redirect to root.
       root_path
   end
```

(Also make sure you have the latest version of Devise)